# TestUnit: Is database the same before each test method is called?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit

I'm trying to find a simple summary of the TestCase lifecycle. Basically, I want to know if I can assume the database state is the same before each test method is called.

What I think happens is:

- I initialise running all tests for MyTestCase on the command-line
- The test database is cleared and fixtures are loaded
- For each test method, a transaction begins, setup is called, the test method is called, teardown is called, and the transaction is rolled back

Is that correct? If so, I could assume the state is the same before each test method. It seems right, but I've seen an inconsistent result and want to be sure I understand the test process before I debug further.

Comment: If you see different data in the DB after the tests run, it means that not all of your tests are rolling back the transaction.

Comment: How can that happen? I'd assume the framework has an `ensure` somewhere to always roll back even if something goes wrong?